# Desplegar aplicación Laravel 8 en servidor IONOS / 1and1

Tags: php, laravel, servidor, composer, despliegue

He realizado una web con Laravel 8 en mi local y ya la tengo lista para subir a un servidor.
Tengo un servidor en IONOS / 1and1 y buscando información no veo nada al respecto y no sé cuales son los siguientes pasos a realizar.

No sé si tiene composer instalado o no o como se tiene que realizar para subir los ficheros (o por ftp o por algún administrador del propio ionos), he visto información por internet muy distinta y no veo claro absolutamente nada.

¿Podríais darme algo de información?
Muchas gracias a todos, espero que esto ayude también a más personas que necesiten esta información.
Un saludo.

Comment: Que cpanel tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Después de ponerme en contacto con IONOS la única posibilidad para desplegar es el servicio de pago Deploy Now con soporte PHP.
Comentar que este sistema no permite acceder por FTP SSH al servidor para gestionar los ficheros.

Answer (score 0):

no se si será el mismo caso pero yo he subido el proyecto al hosting de Ionos, y en la configuración de dominio, en el espacio web he seleccionado la carpeta public. De esta manera ha funcionado, espero sirva de ayuda.